# Problema com autopreenchimento do dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com o dropdownList do asp mvc 5, preciso preencher automaticamente o valor do dropdownlist assim que o usuário entrar na tela de busca, já consegui pegar o valor no banco de dados porém na parte de preencher automaticamente que está dando problema.

Aqui vai direcionar o usuário para tela de Filtro, referente à `div` que ele marcou:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("FiltroQuestao", "Quiz", new { section = "Fisica"})">Questões</a>
```

Aqui vai recuperar o valor da section para poder comprar com o banco

```
public ActionResult FiltroQuestao(string section)
    {

        TempData["Materia"] = section;
        return View();
    }
```

Agora na view estou usando o jquery para preencher o dropdownlist

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Quiz/GetState",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#ddlState').append('<option value="' + value.idMateria + '">' + value.nomeMateria + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Nessa parte estou usando json para poder popular o dropdownlist via ajax

```
 public JsonResult GetState()
    {
        var valorMateria = TempData["Materia"];
        if(valorMateria != null)
        {
            var stateData = db.Materia.Where(x => x.nomeMateria == valorMateria.ToString()).ToList();
            return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        var stateData2 = db.Materia.ToList();
        return Json(stateData2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Esse é o dropdownlist

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ddlState", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Selecionar Materia", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Por padrão ele está vindo como Selecionar Materia, mas quero que venha com o valor que está do banco, que no exemplo é Fisica

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que no retorno do seu Get, você simplesmente adiciona o resultado da Consulta e o `<option>Selecionar Matéria</option>` já está lá.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Quiz/GetState",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {         

       //Removendo os options existentes
       $('#ddlState').find('option').remove();

        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#ddlState').append('<option value="' + value.idMateria + '">' + value.nomeMateria + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Deu certo mas o único problema é se o usuario entrar na URL direto sem passar parâmetro,la no json eu fiz um IF caso ocorresse essa situação,com essa alteração ele tira também o <option>Selecionar Matéria</option> em ambos os casos(não sei se fui muito claro)